# Wireless Mouse Needs USB 2.0

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have the logitech g700s, a 100 dollar wireless mouse. From the first month of use to now (5 months), the mouse does not seem to have its wireless functionality anymore. After unplugging from the charging cable, the mouse and the logitech gaming framework start glitching and crashing and become unusable. Also, if the mouse does start to work wireless, it is not long before it breaks again.

After contacting support, they said that the wifi reciever can only function with USB 2.0, and my computer only has USB 3.0. Is this true, shouldn't a USB 2.0 device work perfectly fine with USB 3.0?

Comment: Your last paragraph is off-topic. I suggest you [edit] your question and remove it.

Comment: Return it and get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue of interference between RF 2400 MHz receivers and USB 3.0 signals. However, I believe the USB 3.0 ports must have some functional device to cause the interference, but who knows. Try to separate the RF dongle from PC body by using a USB cable extender (I can't believe myself advocating an illegal USB interconnect!). As I recall, many Logitech RF devices come with this kind of extender, with a funny receptacle shape.

I this does not help, try to get a USB2 hub, even the cheapest one will do the job (if it works at all with your PC).

Comment: Even using a powered USB 3 hub might make a difference.  At the very least you can plug a USB 2 hub into the USB 3 hub, but that's a ton of work, given the mouse did work which means honestly is likely the dongle anyways

Comment: I am looking for a hub with an sd-card reader for my pc, I will try and get one with USB 2.0 and see if that helps. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

USB 3.0 is completely backward-compatible with USB 2.0. Have you replaced the batteries since you got it?  Or uninstalled and reinstalled the software?  Or tried plugging the dongle into another port?  Otherwise, return/replace the mouse.

Comment: Yes i tried all of those things.